# QGIS Start and endpoint marker line and polyline

Tags: line, polyline-creation

I have a DWG file with lines and polylines.

I would like to know how to make a point at each side of the line. Like a startpoint and a endpoint. I do not want any points in the middle just start and end.

I use Qgis

Comment: You can try to use node tool,  processing panel